# Is there a way to tell if objects have been clipped?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

When a model is published from revit for a single floor of a multi-floor building, objects that extend between the floors can be clipped.  The viewer will give us dbids for these partially displayed objects, but is there a way to know if the part's geometry is not fully loaded?

Our use case is to detect if an object is completely visible in a view, otherwise we need to flag that part as not being fully displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Viewer3D.prototype.getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method to get a list of all properties available for a specific object ID. Among these properties you can find things like Revit Constraints (Base Constraint, Base Offset, Top Constraint, Top Offset) or Dimensions. Perhaps you could use those values to identify whether the object has been clipped or not?

Comment: I don't see how these constraints could tell me whether or not the object is clipped.

Comment: I was assuming you know the particular floor that was published. So, for example, if you're looking at the 2nd floor, and you see an object with Base Constraint set to the 1st floor, or with Top Constraint set to the 3rd floor, wouldn't that be an indication that the object you're seeing is clipped?

Comment: I understand.  This may be a viable option on a floor-by-floor basis with horizontal clipping planes.  If the object is clipped by some vertical clipping plane, we would have to find another indicator.